# Not able to use Stack and Canvas together in flutter

Tags: flutter, canvas, dart, stack, flutter-widget

I have a `Stack` which consist of `Image.asset` and a `canvas` overlay.. if i use the canvas overlay to draw some points over image..then image `GestureDetector` are not working and if i put image over canvas then gestures are working but not able to see points that are drawn over canvas.